# Getting Master-Detail App Template from Xcode 11?

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, xcode

For learning reason, I would like to get back the Master-Detail App template that was available in Xcode 11 and refer to the template codes inside. I also want both the Swift and Objective-C versions. However, to my astonishment it seems no one has asked this question before and seems there were no data source available where I could get back those files.

I try to reinstall my Xcode 12 back to Xcode 11 but that was not allowed as Mac complained that I am using Big Sur and I cannot use Xcode 11 with Big Sur. I also tried to check on YouTube etc. to look for potential useful information about Master Detail App and those existed on YouTube were from Xcode 5 or Xcode 6 or so where the split view controller thing were not in used yet.

I saw a reply online saying Master-Detail App is replaced with simply App and so we can just use App instead from there. That answer is of course factual but practically useless. As that answer assumed readers are pro enough to change between different templates, but if that's the case then readers like I won't need to ask that question in the first place. Readers look for that particular template for a reason, simply telling them to use something different is tautology.

In short, I cannot come up with a way to get back the exact Xcode 11 Master-Detail App template and I really need it for learning purpose. Is there something I can do with it?

Comment: I have no idea if that works (or has unwanted side effects), but you could locate "Master-Detail App.xctemplate" in the Xcode 11 bundle and copy that to the corresponding folder in Xcode 12.

Answer (score 0):

You can search for tutorials (video or article) that uses Xcode 11 and get it from there.